# Merging and grouping multiple csv files with Ipython and pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge, ipython

I desire either something like this:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
100       200       No Value
400       No value  500
```

When CSV files lookes like this:

CSV File 1

```
Column A  Column B
100       200
```

CSV File 2

```
Column A  Column C
400       500
```

I have started importing with something similar to this:

```
file_list = [CSV File 1, CSV File 2]
#Empty list
list = []
for n in range(len(file_list)):
    g = pd.read_csv(file_list[n], delimiter = "\;")
    list.append(g)
#Data frame for all the values
real_list = pd.concat(list, axis = 1)
```

This gives the result of something similar to this.

```
Column A    Column B    Column A    Column B
100         200         400         500
```

Which is wrong.

Any ideas are much appreciated =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform an outer [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [8]:

df.merge(df1, how='outer')
Out[8]:
   Column A  Column B  Column C
0       100       200       NaN
1       400       NaN       500
```

The reason you get that result when using `concat` is that you are concatenating column-wise and it's aligning on the common index values

Comment: Ok, i rewrote the code to make it work. Is it possible to do this within a for-loop so i effectively can merge 10 csv-files together in the same way?

Comment: You'd have to merge each of the files to each other, concat will not produce the csv you're looking for